# How do I get memory usage of chromedriver (selenium) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having a hard time finding solution to my question. It will be great if someone could help me with this. My question is: How do I get memory usage from chromeDriver using selenium in javascript? I came across one module named "chrome-ops". But that isn't working as I am using an older version of js. Can anyone suggest ways to get memory information?

Appreciate your help :)

Thanks!